# R simulation periodic ARMA(1,1)

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

I'd like to simulate a\ periodic ARMA(1,1) using R. I found the R package *perARMA* but I don't understand how to use it.
There is the function *makeparma* that permit to simulated the parma(1,1). But I don't understand the input parameters and the model used to simulate the periodic stuff.

This is the source code provided by the package trying to simulate a parma(2,1):

```
T=12
nlen=480
p=1
a=matrix(0,T,p)
q=1
b=matrix(0,T,q)

a[1,1]=.8                 
a[2,1]=.3                                     
phia<-ab2phth(a) 
phi0=phia$phi         
phi0=as.matrix(phi0)       

b[1,1]=-.7            
b[2,1]=-.6                  
thetab<-ab2phth(b)         
theta0=thetab$phi  
theta0=as.matrix(theta0) 

del0=matrix(1,T,1)       

PARMA21<-makeparma(nlen,phi0,theta0,del0)
parma<-PARMA21$y
```

I don't understand why we should specify two beta value. And why del0 is a matrix.

Comment: Have you read the package documentation first? Install the package and type `?makeparma`

Comment: yes, I read, but there is something I don't understand. I don't know how to  examine in depth the problem. I'd like to have some help for start to understand.

Comment: Provide some sample data using `dput(head(yourdata))` and also some sample code of what you have tried including where you are stuck. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the R package *sarima* and for the simulation I used the function *prepareSimSarima*